# Slow Image Upload and Crunching

Tags: php, wordpress, performance

Good day, I am having some problems with the WordPress crunching all my images which really slows down the process of uploading images. Is there any way of removing the Flash Uploader? I have already added the following code to all the function.php files in my Cpanel:

```
add_filter( 'flash_uploader', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ), 1 );
```

as well as

```
add_filter( 'flash_uploader', create_function( '$a', "return false;" ), 1 );
```

I have also changed the media settings Image sizes all to 0.

Nothing seems to be working it keeps crunching the images when I upload it.
If anyone can help I will really appreciate it as this is driving me crazy now.

The internet connection speed is perfect 100mb per sec. File size and resolution of the images are good. Hosting server is perfect as the other sites have no issues at all. Also not the plugins as I have already checked them as well.

Comment: what do you mean **crunching all my images**

Comment: https://pharoahgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Screenshot-2019-04-25-at-12.04.21.png

Comment: please check link above it takes way to long as it crunches images first

Comment: so stop crunching. what plugin do you use for crunching?

Comment: Do not use any plugin wp does it automatically to make 3 versions of the same image. It is a feature in wordpress itself that I can not get rid of even when adding the coding in theme function php etc

Comment: nope. it's not. wordpress **do**  create 3 multiple sizes, but not this